# UI Bug During Review

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

When reviewing close votes, the pop up that shows reasons to close will sometimes mangle text.

[image: NUTS]

Comment: Should be fixed - see this MSE post - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301503/misaligned-options-still-in-the-close-vote-popup-dialog

Comment: @bluefeet woohoo! thanks, ma'am!